# Data validation to display with indicators using jqGrid Free

Tags: jqgrid

I am working with jqGrid, but I'm quite rusted.

I'm trying to figure out how to do this. Assume I have a REST controller which returns a collection of grid data.

Say for a specific row : row1 -> col1, col2, col3 have the values as response 1, 3, 4 respectively

Now, I have a validation Excel file, which I have pull out their corresponding values for validation say 1, 5, 6 for row1

How, after getting response back, how to loop through all rows to compare with the validation set value to flag errors so I can display jqGrid to show 1 as green and 3 an 4 as red, or similar way next to them an indicator like a green checkmark or an X to say validation tests have failed.

Finally, I need to display in the end the final grid, which test has been successfully completed.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: My bad. Thanks for the reminder.